# How to prevent multiple loads in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, data-structures, loading

I've got a class hierarchy in C# describing some data structure. There are base classes, which automate and perform some general tasks and on top of them there are specialized classes, which reflect the actual structure.

I want that structure to be able to be loaded only once. If you load it - or modify any of its fields - loading should no longer be available.

I came up with three solutions:

1. Create a flag `bool loaded` field and set it when class is loaded (or changed).

   **Pros**: Structure does not have to be changed from what it currently is, straightforward usage (`new` + `.Load()`)

   **Cons**: I would have to work hard to propagate this flag throughout the whole structure and generally take care of it, such that it would be updated in every possible case. Also, this is runtime solution (second load = exception), while I always prefer compile-time solutions.
2. Move the loading to constructor of class, such that one might create an empty structure or create it and load immediately after.

   **Pros**: Compile-time solution: one would not be able to simply load the structure at any time.

   **Cons**: Loading relies on derived classes and virtual methods cannot be called in the constructor, what complicates things. This can be overcome, but in the cost of simplicity of the interface. Also it happens, that while loading, I have to return a object, what would require the ctor to have an `out` parameter (that seems to be a necessity anyway).
3. Create class factory, hide the ctor and provide factory methods for creating empty and pre-loaded structure.

   **Pros**: Compile-time solution. Factory can be generic to cover all derived classes

   **Cons**: Complicated code and non-intuitive interface (factories are a little less obvious way to create things than `new` operator). Also, this solution relies on `internal` modifier to make the structure and factory friends.

My questions are:

- Is there a better way to prevent one from loading a structure a few times?
- Or: is there a way to overcome downsides of proposed solutions?

---

**Edit:** In response to answers

Think of my structure as of Word document or Excel sheet. Word document can only be loaded once, you cannot "call load" on already loaded document. This is a kind of security measure I want. In other words I want to prevent someone from calling:

```
MyStructure s = new MyStructure();
s.Load("file1.str");
s.Load("file2.str"); // Doesn't make sense
```

And also:

```
MyStructure s = new MyStructure();
s.SomeProperty = 15;
s.Load("file1.str"); // Doesn't make sense
```

Comment: Which framework version are you using? I think you could use `Lazy<T>` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997286(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: Does it even make sense to set properties of a non-loaded (i.e. "new") instance? If not, using some kind of a load factory is pretty much a no-brainer.

Comment: Actually, it makes sense (as it makes perfect sense to modify newly created Word document :))

Answer (score 0):

You should use an [Identity Map](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/identityMap.html) for that. It keeps track of which entities have already been loaded.

Comment: This is also a caching mechanism, I'm afraid, that it won't work in my case. Please read the updated question.

Answer (score 0):

Additional cons:

1 - Your data object is no longer holding just business data - it's also holding a loaded state - this is against the [SRP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

3 - Factories may have to change when more types are created - this will mean more maintenance

It looks like you are using the active record pattern. I would not use the [active record pattern](http://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/activeRecord.html) as it combines business data and data loading - this is against the [SRP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

Instead, use the repository pattern with [POCO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_CLR_Object)s to create your objects.

However, if you are keeping the current code you could add checks in the `Load` method - if the file name is different to the current file name (surely a property) prevent the load because it doesn't make sense in this context.

Comment: Can you elaborate? Suppose, that you have a `WordDocument` class containing the loaded document on which user works. How would you prevent loading it from one file and a moment later loading it from another file? (eg. `doc.Load("File1.doc"); doc.Load("File2.doc");` - that doesn't make much sense and I want to protect my structure against such actions)

Comment: I may be confused but if you load File2.doc that would open a new document. You would have two completely different object trees that reflect the two different files.

Comment: From the perspective of the program logic, yes. But the "Load" method simply loads contents of the structure from file. Calling it on the already opened document doesn't make much sense (what should happen? Should they be merged? The older one replaced with new one?) and I want to protect my code from doing so (preferably, in the compile time).

Comment: Load should create a new object tree - so no merge or replace, just a new data structure. It sounds like you are using the active record pattern? If so that is a problem with Active Record - your data population and data object are combined... If you have a repository (look at repository pattern) that loads your data object this may not be a problem.

Answer (score -2):

> I want that structure to be able to be loaded only once.

Have you looked at the [Singleton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)?

The singleton pattern restricts the instantiation of a class to one object.  Using the pattern will ensure you are not re-inventing the wheel.

However, I am not sure if you really only want one object in your application, or you want to ensure your code doesn't retrieve the data more than once for performance reasons - hence two answers.

Comment: I'm affraid, that a singleton doesn't have much to do with my problem (though I didn't downvoted - just for the record)

Comment: I just thought you might be trying to ensure single instantiation, fair enough if that isn't the case.

Comment: There is a difference between loading the same object twice or instantiating the same class twice...

Comment: Hello Eric, I'm not sure if that is a question or statement? If a question, yes there is a difference.